# Gnome shell theme changed automatically

Tags: 17.10, themes, gnome-shell

On a fresh install of ubuntu 17.10 I enabled gnome extensions and logged out. When i logged back on the appearance changed completely. [image]

No icons, Low resolution text
[image]

plus there is a new panel at the bottom.
I guess this is the default gnome look. There wasn't even ubuntu dock. I had to add it. I tried changing themes but no luck. I would like to have my stock look restored. It looks ugly.[image]

Answer (score 0):

So i have figured it out. This happened due to  installation of gnome-shell-extensions from ubuntu repositories. Removing it fixed the problem .